# Decrementing db value of every row in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want a method to reduce every value in a column (credit) by a specified amount. I have tried:

```
User.all.map! {|user| user.credit -= 50}
```

which just maps the credit, rather than the user. I feel like the correct answer is to use

```
User.update_all(something)
```

but I don't know how to update a value relative to its previous value using this method.

This seems like a common requirement so I'm guessing there's a standard approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass string to `update_all` like in this example:

```
User.update_all("credit = credit - 50")
```

SQL which will be exectued:

```
UPDATE "users" SET credit = credit - 50
```

Comment: Note that validations and callbacks are not invoked in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can update `User.all`, just iterate on all the rows and don't forget to save each record:

```
User.all.each do |user|
  user.credit = user.credit - 50
  user.save!
end
```

but the more efficient way would be updating all the rows in the database. You can issue an SQL like:

```
UPDATE users SET credit = credit - 50;
```

Comment: `find_each` is generally preferably when iterating over all records, since it batches the fetches.

Answer (score 1):

You should use either [`update_all`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_all/class), as suggested by @sufleR, or [`find_each`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/ClassMethods/find_each):

```
User.find_each{ |user| user.update!(credit: uuser.credit - 50) }
```